# Problema utilizando sockets en python

Tags: python-3.x, socket

Hola a todos tengo un problema resulta que estoy haciendo un programa cutlizando sockets pero por alguna extrana raon aparece el error de broken pipi por lo que  he leido est error suele suceder cuando escribe en un socket completamente cerrado en el otro lado (cliente) pero no entiendo poruqe me aparece si las conexiones de ambos tanto la del ssevidor como la del cliente las tengo abierta

Ademas si me puede explciar a lujo  de detalle para que sirven estas dos lienas o que demonis estoy haciendo ocn eso ya queheencontrado informacion en internet  o en la api de socket de python y no me queda claro para que se utiliza

```
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1
```

codigo del cliente

```
host ='127.0.0.1'
        port = 5555
        TAM_BUFFER_ENVIO=4096
        TAM_BUFFER_RECEPCION = 4096
        client =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
        client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_SNDBUF,TAM_BUFFER_ENVIO)
        client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_RCVBUF,TAM_BUFFER_RECEPCION) 
        client.connect((host,port))
        username=instancia_login_chat.line_edit_user_usuario.text()
        try:
            
            message=client.recv(self.recv).decode('utf-8')
            if message == "@username":
                client.send(username.encode("utf-8"))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            print("An error Ocurred")
            client.close()
```

codigo del servidor

```
import socket
import threading

class Servidor ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.host ="127.0.0.1"
        self.port = 5555
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
        TAM_BUFFER_ENVIO=4096
        TAM_BUFFER_RECEPCION = 4096
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY,1)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_SNDBUF,TAM_BUFFER_ENVIO)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_RCVBUF,TAM_BUFFER_RECEPCION) 
        self.server.bind((self.host,self.port))
        self.server.listen(10)
        print("Servidor corriendo") 

    clients=[]
    usernames=[]
    def broadcast(self,message,username,_client):
        for client in self.clients:
            if client != _client:
                client.send(message)
    def handle_messages(self,client,username):
        while True:
            try:
                message=client.recv(1024)
                self.broadcast(message,username,client)
            except Exception as e:
                index = self.clients.index(client)
                username=self.usernames[index]
                self.broadcast(("XPLOT RAT WIFI CHAT --->"+ username+"DESCONEATADO",username,client).encode("UTF-8"))
                self.clients.remove[client]
                self.usernames.remove[username]
                client.close()
                break
    recv=1024
    def receive_connections(self):
        while True:
            client, address=self.server.accept()
            client.send("@username".encode("utf-8"))
            username = client.recv(self.recv).decode("utf-8")
            self.clients.append(client)
            self.usernames.append(username)
            print(username + "ESTA CONECTADO CON LA DIRECCION---> " + str(address))
            message = (username+" SE UNIO AL CHAT" ).encode("utf-8")
            self.broadcast(message,username,client)
            client.send("CONECTADO A SERVIDOR".encode("utf-8"))
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_messages, args=(client,username))
            thread.start()
```

Aqui una captura de pantalla del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "me aparece si las conexiones de ambos tanto la del ssevidor como la del cliente las tengo abierta" esta frase, y luego esta frase "que demonis estoy haciendo ocn eso ya queheencontrado informacion en internet o en la api de socket de python y no me queda claro para que se utiliza" implican, que no podes asegurar que tus conexiones esten bien... como sabes que estan abiertas y conectadas? en donde de todo tu codigo podes asegurar eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eran dos preguntas en una. Tienes ya una respuesta que espero te ayude con tu problema. En esta otra respuesta me centraré en tus otras dudas, acerca de qué hacen estas dos líneas:

```
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```

En ambos casos el uso de `setsockopt()` permite activar o desactivar una característica especial de un socket o de un protocolo. El 1 final indica que se está activando, en este caso. Veamos qué son esas características.

### SO_REUSEADDR

Es una opción del socket. Indica que si cuando más adelante se intente hacer la operación `.bind((ip, puerto))` se descubre que esa `ip` y ese `puerto` ya estaban siendo usados, se reusen de todas formas. Sin esa opción el intento de hacer `.bind()` sobre una IP y puerto en uso causaría una excepción y que el programa abortara.

¿Cuándo usarla? En general no debería usarse esta opción, pues si efectivamente tenías en la máquina otro proceso escuchando en esa misma IP y puerto, estarías interfiriendo con él.

De todas formas puede (y suele) usarse cuando estás haciendo muchas pruebas de poner en marcha servidores y clientes que se caen a menudo (o a los que abortas con Ctrl-C). En este caso, debido a cómo funciona el protocolo TCP, incluso si el proceso que tenía abierto el socket ya se ha muerto, el puerto en que escuchaba puede quedar ocupado unos minutos. Ello se debe a que el operativo permanecerá a la escucha en ese puerto por si llegaran paquetes adicionales de cierre de la conexión TCP. Transcurrido un tiempo el operativo liberará el puerto de todas formas.

Así que si se está de pruebas, sucederá a menudo que al tratar de arrancar de nuevo el servidor se encuentre el puerto "ocupado" y no te deje, cuando en realidad ya no estaría ocupado realmente por haber muerto el proceso que lo tenía. En este caso tendrías que esperar unos minutos a que se libere o bien escuchar en un puerto diferente. Ambas opciones suelen ser un incordio, por lo que se suele usar la opcion `SO_REUSEADDR`. Eso permite relanzar inmediatamente en el mismo puerto sin error.

### TCP_NODELAY

Esta opción pertenece al protocolo TCP. Este protocolo tiene incorporado un algoritmo llamado [Algoritmo de Nagle](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Nagle) que intenta hacer algo más eficiente el uso de la red. Si TCP detecta que la aplicación está intentando enviar a menudo paquetes pequeños de datos por la conexión, entonces en lugar de enviarlos inmediatamente, se esperará a haber recibido la confirmación de los enviados previamente. Sólo después de haber recibido esa confirmación, enviará más datos. Entretanto lo que hace es ir acumulándolos.

Por ejemplo, imagina que tu código tiene un bucle de este estilo:

```
for i in range(1000):
  sock.send(bytes[i])
```

Este bucle intenta enviar 1000 bytes de un array por el socket, pero los intenta enviar de uno en uno. TCP enviará el primer byte y retornará a tu bucle. Tu bucle inmediatamente después intentará enviar el siguiente byte, pero TCP probablemente esta vez no lo enviará, sino que comprobará antes si ya ha llegado la confirmación de que el antes enviado ha sido recibido (el otro extremo de la conexión se ocupará de enviar esa confirmación automáticamente, no tienes que programar nada, es parte de cómo está implementado TCP en el operativo). Si la confirmación no ha llegado aún, en lugar de enviar el byte que tu código le ha pedido que envíe, lo guadará en un almacén y retornará inmediatamente a tu código. Eso se repetirá varias veces (pues tu código sigue en el bucle y sigue llamando a `.send()`.

Cuando en una de esas llamadas a `.send()` TCP descubra que por fin le ha llegado la confirmación del primer byte, entonces enviará de golpe todos los que tenía pendientes en su almacén, y retornará a tu código. Éste seguirá tratando de enviar bytes de 1 en 1, pero TCP de nuevo los acumulará a la espera de la siguiente confirmación, etc...

Ese comportamiento que he descrito es el algoritmo de Nagle y está activado por defecto. En general es bueno que funcione así, pues es más eficiente con el uso de la red. En lugar de enviar muchos paquetitos IP con un solo byte en cada uno, acumula la información para enviarla junta en paquetes más grandes.

Cuando usas la opción `TCP_NODELAY` estás **desactivando el algoritmo de Nagle**. Por tanto en ese caso cada byte se enviará inmediatamente sin esperar por la confirmación de los bytes previos. Este comportamiento en general es menos deseable (por eso esa no es la opción por defecto), pero en algunos casos puede ser interesante, para reducir la latencia percibida por el usuario (por ejemplo en videojuegos, aunque para estos casos quizás sería mejor usar UDP en lugar de TCP).

Answer (score 1):

La línea que te genera el error es:

```
self.broadcast(message,username,client)
```

que te lleva a ejecutar:

```
    def broadcast(self,message,username,_client):
        for client in self.clients:
            if client != _client:
                client.send(message)
```

En resumen, el problema se ocasiona cuando tu conectas varios clientes al servidor, pero cierras el programa de alguno de ellos. Al cerrar el programa, el socket TCP que estaba escuchando y que representaba a ese cliente queda cerrado, cualquier intento de mandar un mensaje te va generar una excepción como la que tienes.

Para solucionarlo tienes varias alternativas:

1. Healthcheck. Mecanismo que cada n segundos verifica que la conexión con tus clientes este abierta. Puedes mandar un paquete sentinela que tanto el cliente como el servidor entiendan y que simplemente responda con una respuesta para confirmar la salud de la comunicacion, en caso de que no se reciba esa respuesta, puedes confirmar que el cliente esta offline y lo eliminas de tu lista de clientes.
2. Simplemente capturar esa excepción en el broadcast y en caso de que se genere, eliminar a ese cliente de la lista de clientes.

Es importante notar que aunque la solución 2) es la más sencilla, no es la correcta, en especial cuando estas manejando las conexiones a través de hilos y cada conexión con un cliente (aun cuando ya no esta activa) te requiere tener un hilo activo.

La primera opción es la mas correcta pero demanda un diseño más rígido del programa, ademas de que requiere que captures la excepción en tu método de broadcast, principalmente por que aún se puede generar una condición de carrera en la cual el mecanismo de healthcheck aún no haya detectado una conexión muerta y se genere un llamado a broadcast.

Otra cosa importante es que cualquier implementación que hagas debe considerar que estas utilizando concurrencia, puedes tener problemas con condiciones de carrera.

Adicionalmente, si el programa que estas usando lo pones bajo condiciones más estrictas (cliente/servidor en una red externa, comunicación con payloads mayores al tamaño del búfer con el recibes), va fallar. Manejar sockets es una tarea ardua, con muchas situaciones que no se ven a simple vista, te recomiendo leer este [post](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) para una explicación más profunda.